# IE11 developer tools - document mode and user agent string are blank

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I am experiencing an issue where the document mode and user agent string select boxes in the emulation tab are blank when I am using the IE 11 Developer Tools. Here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image: Dev Tools Blank]

I have researched the issue and have tried the following recommended solutions:

- Deleting registry key from HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ Internet Settings\5.0\LowCache\Extensible Cache
- Running IE11 in administrator mode
- Deleting %TEMP%\TempIE

From these posts:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-iewindows8_1/document-mode-and-user-agent-string-dropdowns/cd34d5f8-7839-4083-af55-05d49ba85190?page=1

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/970c16ca-8ae8-49e7-bced-ddce437c690d/internet-explorer-11-emulation-document-mode-and-user-agent-string-drop-down-menu-blank?forum=ieitprocurrentver

These have not worked unfortunately. There is currently a [bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/808143/ie11-emulation-screen-document-mode-and-user-agent-dropdowns-blank-for-all-sites/) open for this issue on MS connect. However there has been no reply from microsoft since November 2013. Has anyone else experienced this issue and are aware of a functioning workaround?

Comment: In addition to the above suggestions (as well as the suggestions of running as administrator, or disabling Protected mode), uninstalling Internet Explorer 11 (**Programs and Features** -> **Turn Windows Features on or off** -> **Internet Explorer 11**) and reinstalling does not fix it either.

Comment: @IanBoyd You're telling me that running as admin, etc don't fix the issue for you?!

Comment: @MilindR Yes. While **I** may be running as an administrator, and the *host* Internet Explorer process may be running as an administrator, the browser *tabs* are not. Chrome and Internet Explorer make use of a security feature introduced in Windows Vista. Both Chrome and IE run each browsing tab in a separate *"Low"* process (with permissions lower than that of Administrator, and lower than that of a standard user). It helps to ensure that even if the user is running as an administrator, that the browser cannot write to any place not white-listed.

Comment: @IanBoyd Ah I see you wrote the currently accepted answer... Now I understand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue happens when the Internet Explorer browser tab process in unable to access the appropriate **Low** folder.

Internet Explorer when running in *Protected Mode*, runs each tab in a separate **Low Mandatory Integrity Level** process. Any process tagged as **Low** [has a number of restrictions placed upon it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625962.aspx), e.g.:

- limiting write access to only one folder on the hard drive (LocalLow)
- limiting write access to only one key in the registry (AppDataLow)
- blocks window and process hooking
- unable to create processes or remote threads
- cannot write to shared memory
- access running COM objects
- cannot access clipboard
- cannot open sockets
- cannot initiate RPC
- cannot send messages to other windows

The interesting restriction we care about is only able to write to specifically white-listed folders; folders marked with **Low Mandatory Integrity Level**.

An example of one of these folders is your **LocalLow** folder in:

- `C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local`
- `C:\Users\Ian\AppData\LocalLow` *(low integrity level)*
- `C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming`

You can see the **Low Mandatory Integrity Level** tag applied to this folder by running `icacls` from an elevated command prompt:

```
C:\Users\Ian\AppData>icacls LocalLow
LocalLow BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
         BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
         NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
         NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)
         BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
         BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
         Mandatory Label\Low Mandatory Level:(OI)(CI)(NW)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

The last entry:

> Mandatory Label\Low Mandatory Level

indicates that this folder has the **Low** integrity level marker. This means that it is one of the few folders that a **Low** process is allowed to write to.

## What does this have to do with Internet Explorer

In the case of Internet Explorer, there are a handful of other **Low** folders.

```
C:\Users\Ian\AppData\LocalLow
C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local\Temp\Low
C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Low
C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\IECompatCache\Low
C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\IECompatUACache\Low
```

When you use the F12 tools, Internet Explorer tries to access the `IECompatUACache` folder. If the folder does not have the correct label, the `iexplore.exe` process will get an `ACCESS DENIED` error; causing it fail badly.

What can cause the **Low Mandatory Label** to have been lost from one of these folders or any of their subfolders? Perhaps you own an SSD, and tried to use [Microsoft's supported feature of relocating your `AppData` folder](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/redirect-folder-new-location#1TC=windows-7). The folder relocation feature fails pretty spectacularly at its one job of relocating a folder.

In order to reset the **Mandatory Integrity Level Low** label on the `Low` folders around the computer, run:

```
icacls "D:\Users\Ian\AppData\LocalLow" /setintegritylevel low /T
icacls "D:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local\Temp\Low" /setintegritylevel low /T
icacls "D:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Low" /setintegritylevel low /T
icacls "D:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\IECompatCache\Low" /setintegritylevel low /T
icacls "D:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\IECompatUACache\Low" /setintegritylevel low /T
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I first tried the answer above with protected mode, however that was just a workaround. THIS is the fix.

Comment: What a spectacularly perfect answer. After relocating the user's folder using Windows audit mode, IE experienced a multitude of issues, including F12 not working and some Javascript not working. I created all the directories above, then changed permissions as per your instructions and those problems disappeared. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You can disable Protected Mode in IE, that fixes the issue too. Less dangerous than running it as administrator.

Comment: +1! This is the definite answer and should be the accepted one. (ping @rizebyte)

Comment: I'll keep an eye on it @progo. If more people find it useful compared to the current top answer, I will accept this one.

Comment: @RyanHendry As I understand, you should accept whatever answer works for you, irrespective of how many others like it (that's what votes are for).

Comment: +1! And to disable Protected Mode in IE: Tools > Internet Options > Security > uncheck "Enable Protected Mode"

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue too for a while. If you still need a quick fix, running Internet Explorer with Administrator Privileges seems to refresh the list for me, whenever it's empty. Hope that helps!

Comment: This worked for me as well, but when NOT running in Administrator mode the list is empty again.

Answer (score 1):

With IE11 RTM those lists are populated from a service, when that fails the lists are empty :(. With the April update to IE11 the fall back should be a default list of entries rather than blank. Try installing the latest Windows Update.

Comment: I am running 11.0.9600.17105 which is the latest version I think.